# $M\subset N$ over Dedekind domain $O$. If module index $[M:N]=0$, then $M=N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $M,N$ be two torsion free modules over Dedekind domain $O$ with same rank. Suppose $M\subset N$. Then one can talk about module index $[M:N]_O$. Module index is defined in terms of local field automorphism $l_p:M_p\to N_p$ which exists by PID. Then $[M_p:N_p]_{O_p}=det(l_p)O_p=p^{k_p}O_p$. Then $[M:N]_O=\prod_{p\in Spec(O)}p^{k_p}$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ If $[M:N]_O=O$ for $N\subset M$, do I know $M=N$? It is clear that $M\cong N$. Do I know this morphism is $M=N$ morphism?

Comment: Try showing that $M_{\mathfrak p} = N_{\mathfrak p}$ for all primes $\mathfrak p$ of $O$.

Comment: @D_S Indeed, $M_p\subset N_p$ and use PID classification theorem yields the result.